# Представление чисел для символьных вычислений C#

Tags: c#, математика, интерпретатор

Здравствуйте! Сейчас я пытаюсь написать простую математическую программу - вычисление выражений, решение уравнений и систем уравнений. Использую голый C#, в связке с Antlr.

Вычисления выражений я осилил, но только для рациональных чисел. Хотелось бы мочь вычислять выражения типа
**sqrt(32)+sqrt(8)**.

В данный момент, для представления чисел используется простой класс **Fract**, содержащий метод **simplify** для сокращения дроби, два конструктора (из двух чисел - числителя и знаменателя, и строки, с возможным знаком '/'), и перегрузки для операторов +-/*.

```
public class Fract
{
    public int num;
    public int denom;

    public Fract(int n, int d)
    {
        num = n;
        denom = d;
        simplify();
    }

    public Fract(string str)
    {
        if(str.Contains("/"))
        {
            string []arr = str.Split('/');
            num = Convert.ToInt32(arr[0]);
            denom = Convert.ToInt32(arr[1]);
        }
        else 
        {
            num = Convert.ToInt32(str);
            denom = 1;
        }
    }

    public void simplify()
    {
        int a = num;
        int b = denom;

        while(a!=b)
        {
            if(a>b)
                a-=b;

            else
                b-=a;
        }

        num/=a;
        denom/=b;
    }

    public static Fract operator+ (Fract a, Fract b)
    {
        int d = a.denom * b.denom;
        int n = a.num*b.denom + b.num*a.denom;
        return new Fract(n, d);
    }

    public static Fract operator- (Fract a, Fract b)
    {
        int d = a.denom * b.denom;
        int n = a.num*b.denom - b.num*a.denom;
        return new Fract(n, d);
    }

    public static Fract operator* (Fract a, Fract b)
    {
        int d = a.denom * b.denom;
        int n = a.num*b.num;
        return new Fract(n, d);
    }

    public static Fract operator/ (Fract a, Fract b)
    {
        int d = a.denom * b.num;
        int n = a.num*b.denom;
        return new Fract(n, d);
    }

    public static explicit operator string(Fract a)
    {
        if(a.denom == 1)
            return Convert.ToString(a.num);

        return Convert.ToString(a.num)+'/'+Convert.ToString(a.denom);
    }
}
```

Как нужно хранить числа с корнями и функциями (**sin**, **cos**)? Информации в интернете не нашел. Спасибо.

Comment: тут вряд ли есть однозначный ответ. Можно попробовать по аналогии с комплексными числами, ввести дополнительный множитель к числителю и знаменателю обозначающий корень из некоторого числа. Все зависит от того, что вы хотите получить на выходе.

Comment: Мне кажется вам нужно посмотреть в сторону разбора выражений (подраздел разработки компиляторов). Поскольку вы сейчас пытаетесь запихнуть всё в один класс, а оно так явно не ляжет. Выглядит как будто вам нужно построить синтаксическое дерево и дальше его трансформировать согласно каким-то собственным правилам.

Comment: @ОлегНечитайло Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.